# Views Animations Queue

Tags: java, android

I have a few `Views` on the page. It is necessary that each animated after the previous one.

1) I thought for each animation to make delays, but it seems to me that this option is not correct.

2) For each animation in the `Listener` in the `onAnimationEnd()` method, I call the next animation. I take animations from `xml`. In this decision, I noticed that the next animation does not immediately work. And I have a 8-10 `Views` and for everyone to implement the `Listener`, it also somehow does not work cleanly.

There are only 3 `Views`, and it takes up so much space:

```
mLogo.startAnimation(zoomInAnim);
    zoomInAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            mPackage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mPackageBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mPackage.startAnimation(slideUpAnim);
            mPackageBack.startAnimation(slideUpAnim);
            slideUpAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    mImage1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mImage1.startAnimation(slideUpBounceAnim);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
}
```

**Question**: How do you combine `Views` and the animation queue, maybe there are other solutions that I don’t know about?

Comment: see `android.animation.AnimatorSet` documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this if your animation have the same length:

```
ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<>(3);
int delay = 0;
for(View view : views){
    view.animatate....setStartDelay(delay);
    delay += 1000;
}
```

There is no reason your animation does not start immediately I wrote a custom digit spinner view and it gets a number like 1000 and using this approach goes from 0 to 1000 for example and uses 2000 animations there's no lag.Check your animations and make sure they're okay,there's no delay and the start of the xml that you defined and forgot.If you want to make sure it's a problem of your animation and the resources just use:

> https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations

It has all of your animations in it by default just choose a few and give it a test.